# How I can group containers in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using this docker-compose.yml.
And I wanna make simpler and inherrit configuration, if its possible.

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

    web_one:
        container_name: "web_one"
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web.docker
        volumes:
            - ./../one:/var/www

        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami_one.local
        links:
            - app_one
    app_one:
        container_name: "app_one"
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./../one:/var/www
        links:
            - db


    web_two:
        container_name: "web_two"
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web.docker
        volumes:
            - ./../two:/var/www

        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami_two.local
        links:
            - app_two
    app_two:
        container_name: "app_two"
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./../two:/var/www
        links:
            - db
```

I have 15 sites with same configuration.
Can I make config simpler? Like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        container_name: nginx-proxy
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

    one:
        extends:
            file: common-services.yml
        volumes:
            - ./../one:/var/www

        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami_one.local

    two:
        extends:
            file: common-services.yml
        volumes:
            - ./../two:/var/www

        environment:
            - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami_two.local
```

Or better?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try it? That is documented in https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#/understand-the-extends-configuration.

Comment: Yes, but can't make it shorter. Same amount of code

Comment: Not that I know of beside what is explained in https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE 31 Aug 2021** In the latest docker compose there's support for *profiles* https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/ so this problem would be perfectly solved by that new feature.

---

Another way is to create no-op services that depend on other services.
For example, in the following `docker-compose.yml` I have two namespaces, dev for services needed when developing the app, and metrics for services related to visualizing app metrics (since I'm not interested instarting those when developing).

```
version: "3"
services:
  dev:
    image: tianon/true
    depends_on: ["postgres", "keycloak"]
  metrics:
    image: monroe/noop
    depends_on: ["grafana"]
  postgres: ...
  keycloak: ...
  grafana: ...
```

Comment: Another good explanation of this is [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2589#issuecomment-313796200).

Comment: `monroe/noop` repo is gone. I used `tianon/true`.